# Scrollify js issue with MAC touchpad

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using scrollify js plugin fot fit-to-screen functionality in my website
here is link of plug in https://projects.lukehaas.me/scrollify/

It`s look good in all windows but If you use the touchpad of the MAC it is very difficult to scroll only one page, often one page is skipped. I don't know if it's possible to enhance, but would be great.